# DotnetCore - Why the app tool throws "System.Resources.Extentions" exception?

Tags: .net-core, servicestack

I am new to the [SharpApp](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-apps) By ServiceStack and Dotnet Core. I were trying to [Pascel WebApp Template](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/parcel-webapp) the following article to setup the basic SharpApp. In the SharpApp article, they have to setup/install dotnet tools.

I tried these:

```
$ dotnet tool install -g x
```

Then

```
$ x open
```

I can see the list of available apps (pre defined apps by Service Stack)

Then I do this

```
$ dotnet tool install -g app
```

Then

```
$ app open
```

I got the exception:
[image]

I am not quite, what I am missing. Any one have idea? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue with the last `app` update, it's been resolved with the latest `0.0.49` release now on NuGet which you can update to after NuGet has finished indexing the package:

```
$ dotnet tool update -g app
```

Comment: Still same problem.

Comment: @Jamil weird I just tried uninstalling/reinstalling on 2 pcs and still works. Can you try doing the same `dotnet tool uninstall -g app` then check that no `app` tool exists then install again with `dotnet tool install -g app`?